# How can I get lengths of values for each of the key in a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

Below is my dictionary. I am trying to calculate lengths of values for each key.Can somebody please help me?

```
My_data = {1: [1450.0, -80.0, 840.0, -220.0, 630.0, 780.0, -1140.0], 2: [1450.0, -80.0, 840.0, -220.0, 630.0, 780.0, -1140.0],3:[ 720.0, -230.0, 460.0, 220.0, 710.0, -460.0, 90.0] }
```

This is what I have tried:

```
for k, v in My_data .iteritems():
        print k, len(v)
```

The desired output is [1:len(values), 2:len(values)]

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: It does not give answer. It throws some error.

Comment: What is the output vs the desired output?

Comment: @A.S "It throws some error" is an exceedingly unhelpful problem description. You need to state what the errors are if you need help with your solution.

Comment: Is your desired output a list or a dictionary? Your example isn't one of them (square brackets - list, colons - dictionary)

Comment: @ Carcigenicate: It throws following error:Error: ('HY000', "[HY000] ERROR:  Unable to identify an operator '=>' for types 'INT4' and 'INT4'\n\tYou will have to retype this query using an explicit cast (46)

Comment: @ Leo : I was looking for a list as output.

Comment: A list of tuples?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Sorry I am just learning python so could not state clearly.

Comment: CoryKramer's answer is what you need. This error doesn't seem so Pythonic to me though.

Comment: Thank you guys. I got the answer what I was looking for

Answer (score 6):

If you just want the lengths, you can use a list comprehension

```
>>> [len(v) for v in My_data.values()]
[7, 7, 7]
```

If you want them associated with each key

```
>>> [tuple((k, len(v))) for k,v in My_data.items()]
[(1, 7), (2, 7), (3, 7)]
```

Or as a new `dict`

```
>>> {k: len(v) for k,v in My_data.items()}
{1: 7, 2: 7, 3: 7}
```